# Regular expression data annotation disallowed start / end spaces (similar to trim)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using a regular expression data annotation to validate a street address field to contains numbers, letters, and spaces (in between). I want the data annotation to throw an error if the street field contains spaces at the beginning or the end of the text entered by the user.

**Example:**

```
// [123 Fake Street] = valid
// [   123 Fake Street] = not valid
// [   123 Fake Street    ] = not valid
// [123 Fake Street   ] = not valid
```

This is what I have so far:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Street Address not valid.")]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about a RegEx that looks for a number/letter to start, ANY number/letter/space in between and ended with a Letter, Number or Symbol (like ".", since Drive can be Dr.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change a little:

```
"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

This means:

1. Get 1 or more letters or numbers and an optional space and repeat 1 or more times;
2. Finish with one or more letters or numbers

You can also write:

```
"^(?:\w+\s?)+\w+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an academic exercise, but could you just trim leading and trailing whitespace from the user's input? Seems like it's just a formatting issue rather than a legitimate error. But if the goal is to better understand RegEx, please disregard my ramblings.

Comment: No. I'm using data annotation to perform ajax form validation. The reason I can't just trim the input is because I have another validation rule for the text length. So if the user has spaces before and after the text, those spaces get counted as the text length and therefore throws the text length error message.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is lack of whitespace this is what you can do:

```
^\S.+\S$
```

This ensures that it starts with a number and ends with a letter, period or number.

This is basically equivalent to:

```
^[^ ].+[^ ]$
```

You can also just look for something that starts with a number and ends with a character or period (for abbreviations)

```
^\d.*[\w\.]$
```